# What happens to a Connection transaction if the ASP page exits unexpectedly?

Tags: asp-classic, transactions, adodb

In classic ASP, what happens to a Connection transaction if the page experiences an uncaught exception and stops before commit/rollback?

For example:

```
conn.BeginTrans

a = 0 / 0

conn.CommitTrans
```

Seeing as the transaction is in progress, will it be aborted or committed? Or will the connection maintain the transaction when it's returned to the connection pool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To return to the connection pool the connection, implicitly or explicitly, should be considered closed. Any transaction pending on connection close will rollback.

BUT while the connection is considered active, the resources/locks adquired in database will still be maintained.

EDIT - From information located by Shadow Wizard (thank you) relative to ADO connection objects: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675814%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Closing a Connection object while there are open Recordset objects on
>   the connection rolls back any pending changes in all of the Recordset
>   objects. Explicitly closing a Connection object (calling the Close
>   method) while a transaction is in progress generates an error. If a
>   Connection object falls out of scope while a transaction is in
>   progress, ADO automatically rolls back the transaction

Comment: Sounds reasonable but do you have official source to confirm this?

Comment: From MS ADO SDK: "If a Connection object falls out of scope while a transaction is in progress, ADO automatically rolls back the transaction."

Comment: OK, you better link to that and put a quote to make your answer more reliable and complete. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I've been unable to find a link to it. Seems that since ado has been replaced with ado.net (and i didn't want to link to it), much of the documentation has been removed. I had to search the .chm files of ADO/MDAC in an old copy of microsoft SDK from the days (years ago) when i was teaching ADO/OLEDB, to copy/paste the quoted text. Sorry, maybe it is online, but i don't know where.

Comment: I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675814(v=vs.85).aspx) - it's about the general ADO and looks good enough.

Comment: Can you please edit your post and add the link? Would do it myself, but best when it comes from the original author. :-)